# Using lock in sub class of threading.Thread in python3

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to ask a question regarding the following code: suppose we wanted to build a `threading.Thread` subclass `ThreadCounter`, such that it has as arugment a name, an initial value and a terminal value and once started it increments the initial value up until it is equal to the terminal one.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

class ThreadCounter(Thread):
   def __init__(self, nome, first, limit, lock):
       # Call the Thread class's init function
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.nome = nome
       self.first = first
       self.limit = limit
       self.lock = lock
       
   # Override the run() function of Thread class
   def run(self):
       while self.first < self.limit:
           self.lock.acquire()
           self.first += 1
           print(self.nome,self.first)
           time.sleep(3)
           
           self.lock.release()
           
         
t1 = ThreadCounter('Thread-1', 1, 5, lock)
t2 = ThreadCounter('Thread-2', 2, 10, lock)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

I do not understand what happens when we are using the locks in the two classes. In particular, are we assigning the same lock-object to both of the instances with the assignment

```
t1 = ThreadCounter('Thread-1', 1, 5, lock)
t2 = ThreadCounter('Thread-2', 2, 10, lock)
```

Or we have a different lock object for every occurence of the ThreadCounter class, such that t1 and t2 do not share the same lock?

Comment: The `id()` function gives you a unique identifier for any Python object. This ID is only reused after an object was destroyed, but for two objects at the same time, it is never the same. I mention that because it allows you to answer your question here yourself and any similar one in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same lock. It would defeat the purpose of locking if each thread had its own lock.

The purpose of locks is to synchronize the two threads to ensure that they aren't executing critical sections at the same time. In this case, the only thing it's effectively locking is `print`, but if the two threads were manipulating a shared resource like a list, the lock would ensure that only one thread is touching the list at a time. This is required since most objects are not safe to operate on across threads at the same time ("non-thread-safe").

---

Look into "synchronization primitives" to understand what the different synchronization options are, and why they're necessary.